# Apache gettext - cache persisting after restart

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, gettext

Running apache2 through Plesk. When I update the `.mo` files via subversion, and then restart apache (either through commandline or through Plesk interface), the translations do not update. Modified timestamps on the files are correct.

Is there any way to manually reset the cache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it wasn't a caching problem.

I had two languages `en_US` and `de_DE`. Gettext was only showing the key and not the translation for `en_US`, which wasn't noticeable because the keys are in English anyway.

So `gettext` was working for one language, and not for another...

Solution:

- Add the `en_US.UTF-8` locale using `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` (I'm on ubuntu).
- Restart apache.

(You can check which locales are installed using `locale -a`.)